# Generating Random Timestamps in Go

Tags: random, go, time

I'd like to generate a random timestamp within the last relative 3 years and have it be printed out with this format: `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z`

Here is what I have right now:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func randomTimestamp() time.Time {
    randomTime := rand.Int63n(time.Now().Unix() - 94608000) + 94608000

    randomNow, err := time.Parse("10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700", strconv.FormatInt(randomTime, 10))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return randomNow
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(randomTimestamp().String())
}
```

This always throws: `panic: parsing time "...": month out of range`. How can I generate a random timestamp for a given range, then convert it to the string format I want with the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use time.Parse. You have a Unix time, not a time string. Use the `Unix()` method instead. https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix. You can also choose a minimum time value, say 1/1/1900 and add a random Duration of seconds to the time using the `Add` method on Time and passing a `Duration` you made with the Ticks() method. https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration

Here's a Go Playground link. Just remember that the Go Playground doesn't support actual randomness. https://play.golang.org/p/qYTpnbml_N

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func randomTimestamp() time.Time {
    randomTime := rand.Int63n(time.Now().Unix() - 94608000) + 94608000

    randomNow := time.Unix(randomTime, 0)

    return randomNow
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(randomTimestamp().String())
}
```